# Can you insert data frame from scala into Teradata stored proc?

Tags: scala, stored-procedures, apache-spark-sql

i'm trying to implement taking a data frame and using that as an input into a stored proc in teradata. here is the code

```
def dfToStoredProc(store_id : String) = {
var connection:Connection = null

Class.forName(driver)
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)

val statement = connection.prepareCall("CALL DB.STORED_PROC(?);")
  
statement.setString(1, store_id)
statement.execute()

}

val dataFrame = df.toDF()

dataFrame.map(m => dfToStoredProc(m.getLong(0).toString))
```

However getting an error, can anyone help?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised my mistake, I forgot to add a collect() statement

```
dataFrame.map(m => dfToStoredProc(m.getLong(0).toString)).collect()
```

An empty dataframe was getting passed to the stored proc which was raising an error